# How to automatically takes a '/'(slash) in textInput field using react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to add functionality to input mm/yy fields so as when the users enters 2 digits, slashes "/" get automatically added.

here's my TextInput

```
<TextInput
placeholder="mm/yy"
placeholderTextColor={Colors.BLACK_TRANSPARENT_50}
keyboardType="number-pad"
maxLength={4}
returnKeyType="done"
style={styles.secondtextinput}
></TextInput>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did something like this in my app for adding a "-" in phone numbers :)
It might be a bit of a roundabout fix, but here's what I did:

I used the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to manage state in my functional component.

```
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
                
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => {
      setDate(
        text.length === 3 && !text.includes("/")
          ? `${text.substring(0, 2)}/${text.substring(2)}`
          : text
      );
    }}
    placeholder="mm/yy"
    placeholderTextColor={Colors.BLACK_TRANSPARENT_50}
    keyboardType="number-pad"
    maxLength={5}
    returnKeyType="done"
    style={styles.secondtextinput}
    value={date}
  />
```

I changed the `maxLength` to 5 to account for the "/". As the user inputs the date, once it gets to a length of 3, it checks for any existing "/"s and, if there aren't any, it adds one in after the second character.

Comment: Great! It actually made me think about it more and modify my own code :)

Comment: Great answer!! Works well

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with the above solution:**

> It adds a slash after text change **i.e.** When a user types the first
> digit of the year (third digit of expiry e.g. 10/2), then a slash will
> be inserted between the newly added digit and the previous digit
> **i.e.** When the user is done with the insertion of 2, then slash will be placed automatically between 0 and 2.

**For a more elegant and robust solution, you can use this solution:**

Create a component scoped variable:

```
let allowChangeText = true;
```

Then create a hook for expiry date text:

```
const [expiryDate, setExpiryDate] = useState('');
```

Later on use the component as:

```
<TextInput
   value={expiryDate}
   maxLength={5}
   keyboardType="number-pad"
   onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
     if (nativeEvent.key == 'Backspace' && expiryDate.length == 3) {
        allowChangeText = false;
        setExpiryDate(expiryDate.substring(0, 2));
     } else {
        allowChangeText = true;
     }
   }}
   onChangeText={(text: string) => {
     if (allowChangeText) {
        setExpiryDate(text.length === 2 && text.indexOf('/') == -1
           ? `${text}/`
           : text
        );
     } else {
        console.log('change text is not of use!');
     }
   }}
 />
```